# SQL - Update certain database records with a loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a certain IDs in a table that I would like to change a column value from false to true. How can I do a loop that goes through the specific IDs given and changes a column value from false to true?

I’m not very familiar with SQL and the only option that came to mind is through a loop.

This is a sample of my data.

[image]

Basically we have a stored procedure to change the “description” of the BetGenerationBetID given from FAILED to SUCCESSFUL example, the below will update the description of BetGenerationBetID 265809596 to SUCCESSFUL

[image]

With the above I can only update a record each time. So I want something that I can give all BetGenerationBetIDs that I want to update and changes the description of each ID at once.

Comment: How are you deciding which failed rows to change to successful? Does the stored procedure have any logic in it other than an update statement? Could you store the stored procedure? Couldn't it be made to take a criteria (or a set) instead of an individual ID?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the BetGenerationBetIDs are given to us by another team so we just input the ID and run the stored procedure. The stored procedure updates all relevant tables not just the one provided above. The parameter is BetGenerationBetID INT so I assume only 1 value.

Comment: Given to you how? In an e-mail? Carrier pigeon? ...? What is the format of the list? Why aren't they just calling the stored procedure?

Comment: They raise a ticket with all bet generation IDs that need to update.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it inside of a procedure with a set amount of `BetGenerationBetID`'s, then you could use [user defined table types](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/creating-a-user-defined-table-type).

**Step 1: Create Type and test table**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.BetGenerationBetIDS AS TABLE  
    ( BetGenerationBetID int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableBetGeneration(BetGenerationBetID int, [description] varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.TableBetGeneration(BetGenerationBetId,[description])
VALUES (1,'Failed'),(2,'Failed'),(3,'Failed');
```

**Step 2: Create the Procedure that uses the table type**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspOverrideBetAsSuccesful
@BetGenerationBetIDTable dbo.BetGenerationBetIDS READONLY
AS
    UPDATE TBG
    SET TBG.[description]   = 'SUCCEEDED'
    FROM  dbo.TableBetGeneration TBG 
    INNER JOIN @BetGenerationBetIDTable AS BGID
    ON TBG.BetGenerationBetID  = BGID.BetGenerationBetID

GO
```

**Step 3: Enter your values and run the procedure**

```
DECLARE @BetGenerationTable as dbo.BetGenerationBetIDs
INSERT INTO @BetGenerationTable(BetGenerationBetID)
VALUES(1),(2)

EXEC dbo.uspOverrideBetAsSuccesful @BetGenerationTable
```

**Validate**

```
SELECT * FROM  dbo.TableBetGeneration
```

**Result**

```
BetGenerationBetID  description
1                   SUCCEEDED
2                   SUCCEEDED
3                   Failed
```